# Que signifie « peu s'en fallut que » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: sens

> À la publication du mémoire sur la propriété, peu s'en fallut que le gouvernement ne se fâchât comme l'Académie.

Je ne comprend pas ce que signifie « peu s'en fallut que » dans cette phrase.

Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a literary way to say the still literary:

> Il s'en fallut de peu que le gouvernement ne se fâche comme l'Académie.

*S'en falloir de peu* (**[B. 1. b](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/falloir))**) roughly means "to miss by few" so the sentence means:

> The Académie (française?) was upset, the government was close to be.

Answer (score 0):

L’inversion de “peu” est semblable a l’inversion anglaise “little did we know”.  L’inversion et la pause engendrée par la virgule précédente permet de mettre l’emphase sur le “peu”, i.e. “how little (or close) it was”.